# cooks distance plot with R

Tags: r, statistics, outliers

Does anybody know, how to grab the single cooks distance plot that you get from this code:

```
treatment <- factor(rep(c(1, 2), c(43, 41)), levels = c(1, 2), labels = c("placebo","treated"))
improved <- factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), c(29, 7, 7, 13, 7, 21)), levels = c(1, 2,3),labels = c("none", "some", "marked"))
numberofdrugs <- rpois(84, 5)+1
healthvalue <- rpois(84,5)
y <- data.frame(healthvalue, numberofdrugs, treatment, improved)
test <- glm(healthvalue~numberofdrugs+treatment+improved, y, family=poisson)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(test) # how to grab plot 2.1 ?
```

What I don't like to have is this

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 1))
plot(test, which=c(4))
```

because it doesn't have residuals on the y axis and leverage on the x axis!

Thanks guys

Comment: Can't you just pass the vector of diagnostic plots you want to `which=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is. You seem to want the plot with residuals on the y axis and leverage on the x axis. Isn't that just the 5th (of 6) plot generated:

```
plot(test,which=5)
```

You can read more about this at ?plot.lm

Edit to address OP's question about setting y axis labels:

Usually, simply adding ylab="My Label" to the plot() call would work, but these graphs are designed to be produced "automatically" and so certain graphical parameters are 'hard coded'. If you pass your own ylab value, you'll get an error, as plot.lm() will be presented with two ylab's and won't know which one to use. If you *really* don't like the y axis label, your only option here is to grab the plot.lm code (just type 'plot.lm' at the console and hit enter) copy and paste it into a text file and look for this section:

```
if (show[5L]) {
    ylab5 <- if (isGlm) 
        "Std. Pearson resid."
    else "Standardized residuals"
    r.w <- residuals(x, "pearson")
    if (!is.null(w)) 
        r.w <- r.w[wind]
    rsp <- dropInf(r.w/(s * sqrt(1 - hii)), hii)
    ylim <- range(rsp, na.rm = TRUE)
    if (id.n > 0) {
        ylim <- extendrange(r = ylim, f = 0.08)
        show.rsp <- order(-cook)[iid]
    }
```

and modify it with your own y axis label. Rename the function (say, plotLMCustomY, or something) and it should work.

Comment: You need plot(test,which=5,caption=""), which I didn't know until you asked. I simply looked it up in ?plot.lm. Read ?plot.lm carefully.

Comment: Thanks you! My enlglish isn't that good, so I often son't see these things :)

Comment: and again... Sorry bout that! But I absolutely don't know how to change the name of the ylabs... '?plot.lm' gives no answer to that question!

Comment: No problem; edited my answer to address the ylab question. Hope it helps!

Comment: And again :D I changed the y axis labels, but unfortunately it seems to be not possible to get rid of the squareroot sign. So when ich name the axis "hello" it shows squarerootsign(hello)... (I am talking about this plot: 'plot(test,which=2)
')

Comment: Not sure quite what you mean. which=3 is the only one that uses a sqrt symbol for me. In which case, find the portion of plot.lm starting with if (show[3L]) and change the value of yl.